# How to manage several kvm from one place?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, qemu, libvirt

good morning.

I have rented 3 physical servers on which I have installed KVM and Virt-Manager.

But it is not very practical for me to have to access each of the 3 servers by VNC to see how everything is going and to manage it.

Is there any way to centralize control of the 3 KVMs?

What suggestion can you give me?

Greetings and thanks

Comment: You could look at using something like Foreman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to run a GUI on the remote systems.

Simply run virt-manager on your local workstation, and let it connect remotely to your three systems via ssh. When you add a connection, you have the option to connect remotely, e.g.:

[image: Virt-manager Add Connection dialog]

Just make sure that you have an ssh key set up to log into the remote root account, and you are ready to go. You can now connect to the remote libvirt and view virtual machines remotely.

[image: Virtual Machine Manager]

Your connection to libvirt, and your connection to the consoles of the remote virtual machines, are automatically tunneled over the ssh connection.

[image: VM graphical console]

There is another way to set up remote connections with TLS and client certificates, but ssh is usually sufficient, and setting up certificates takes some work. If you're interested, the libvirt wiki has [an example setup](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/TLSSetup).